# Show Value in row before the Previous Row in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am building a report in SSRS and wondering how to show the value in the column 2 rows before. I have used the Previous expression to retrieve the one before, but now I need the one before that.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you
Sam

Shared Dataset looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii5y6.jpg

Comment: depending on the structure of your data you might have to use a `LOOKUP()` to get the value or do this in your dataset query. If you can post a sample of your raw data, the output from your dataset query and the output from your report, based on your sample data then I'm sure somebody will have a solution.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me on this. I am using a shared dataset and have shared a sample of this in the original question. I essentially need the sum of the last 4 weeks of sales and if this is 0 mark the store as closed. Do you think this is doable in SSRS? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom code to set and get the value.

```
Public Dim Previous2 As String
Public Dim Previous As String

Public Function SetPrevious2 ( s As String)  As String

Previous2 = Previous
Previous = s

Return Previous2

End Function
```

For the cell use and expression like the one below

```
=  Code.SetPrevious2(Previous(Fields!MyValue.Value))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. I have had a play around and it doesn't seem to be working. I am using a shared dataset which I think is why? I essentially need the sum of the last 4 weeks of sales and if this is 0 mark the store as closed.  Do you think this is doable in SSRS? Thank you